# How can I export my model's properties types from Prisma Schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

Lets say I have this Prisma Schema :

```
model User {
  id             String   @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  email          String   @unique
  username       String   
}
```

Is there a way I can get lets say **email's type** in my app ?

- One options I can come with is a file that will export types but that way everytime I make a change to my prisma schema I will have to go there and manually edit the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prisma by default generates types for all your models.
You could import it like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient, User } from '@prisma/client';
```

Your models will always be in sync with your schema file, anytime you change the schema file, you could execute `npx prisma generate` to update the PrismaClient and the generated types for your models.

Comment: Oh thanks. I totaly forgot about that